# In how many ways can you distribute 18 fruits among 18 pirates so that each gets 1 piece of fruit?

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

> Assume you have 5 oranges, 7 limes, and 6 lemons. How many ways can you distribute these among 18 pirates so they can each get 1 fruit and avoid scurvy?

(This is a **homework** problem)

My first instinct is: $18^{18}$, but that didn't seem right.

My next thought was: $18!$.

The problem doesn't specifically state whether or not repetition counts, so I am not sure what to assume. For instance, if Pirate A gets an orange, does that count for each other orange he could be given?

Comment: I will assume fruit of the same kind are identical (this is an interpretation). Then the pirates who get an orange can be chosen in $\binom{18}{5}$ ways. For every such way, $\dots$.

Comment: My interpretation of this question is that two fruits of the same type are identical and who they are distributed to does not contribute to more possibilities of distribution. In other words, find the number of unique permutations of the string $(O,O,O,O,L,L,L,L,L,L,L,E,E,E,E,E,E)$.

Comment: So then it would be 18 factorial?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not 18 factorial..

When you are arranging items (basically what we're doing here) you have to divide by how many ways each subset of identical items can be arranged.  In this case, there are $18!$ ways to hand out the fruit, but how many ways can you arrange the oranges, limes, and lemons?

Comment: I think I see what you're getting at...18!/(5!7!6!)?

Comment: That is correct.